# Linear Congruential generator in XQuery1.0

Tags: xquery

I wrote (pseudo) random number generator in XQUERY 1.0 using Linear Consequential Method. It works but it is slow. Help me to improve the code:

```
xquery version "1.0";
(:pseudorandom number generator using Linear Congruential Method (LCM). The number generated will be less than $m :)
declare namespace mg = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/maria-kedzierski-36088513b/";
declare variable $m:= 32768; (: select $m to be power of 2 :)
declare variable $a:= 25173;  (: $a=1+4k, where k is an integer and  $a < $m :)
declare variable $c:= 13849; (: $c is relative prime to $m and $c < $m  :)
declare variable $x0:= 16384; (: $X0 < $m :)
declare function mg:random($num as xs:integer) as xs:integer {
 if ($num = 1) then (($a * $x0 + $c) mod $m) else (($a * mg:random($num - 1) + $c) mod $m) };

for $i in (1 to 100) return mg:random($i)
```

Comment: What engine are you running under, and what response times are you getting? The reason I ask is that I implemented using map to cache values and avoid re-calculating `mg:random()` for a number that has already been calculated. This improves the time in MarkLogic dramatically(from 16ms to 1ms), but is slower in eXist (from 52ms to 103ms).

Comment: I was using MarkLogic 9.0, but the code has to be XQuery 1.0 not XQuery 1.0-ml.  Caching values to avoid re-calculating is a good idea. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I profiled the code execution in MarkLogic, the bulk of the time was spent re-calculating number that have already been generated. Leveraging maps, you can cache those calculated values.

Below is an **XQuery 1.0-ml** transform that uses [MarkLogic map functions](https://docs.marklogic.com/map). It reduces the transformation time from 16ms to 1ms.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
(:pseudorandom number generator using Linear Congruential Method (LCM). The number generated will be less than $m :)
declare namespace mg = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/maria-kedzierski-36088513b/";
declare variable $m:= 32768; (: select $m to be power of 2 :)
declare variable $a:= 25173;  (: $a=1+4k, where k is an integer and  $a < $m :)
declare variable $c:= 13849; (: $c is relative prime to $m and $c < $m  :)
declare variable $x0:= 16384; (: $X0 < $m :)

declare variable $cache := map:new();

declare function mg:random($num as xs:integer) as xs:integer {
 let $key := xs:string($num)
 let $cached-value := map:get($cache, $key)
 return
   if ($cached-value) then
    $cached-value
   else
     let $random-value :=
       if ($num = 1) then 
        ($a * $x0 + $c) mod $m
       else 
        ($a * mg:random($num - 1) + $c) mod $m
     return
       (
         $random-value,
         map:put($cache, $key, $random-value)
       )
 };

for $i in (1 to 100) 
return mg:random($i)
```

A pure XQuery 3.1 module using standard maps is below. Although MarkLogic has many 3.x language features, it does not yet allow the syntax for standard [map constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#doc-xquery31-MapConstructor). When I profiled this module in eXist, it actually increased the time from 57ms to 151ms:

```
xquery version "3.1";
(:pseudorandom number generator using Linear Congruential Method (LCM). The number generated will be less than $m :)
declare namespace mg = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/maria-kedzierski-36088513b/";
declare variable $m:= 32768; (: select $m to be power of 2 :)
declare variable $a:= 25173;  (: $a=1+4k, where k is an integer and  $a < $m :)
declare variable $c:= 13849; (: $c is relative prime to $m and $c < $m  :)
declare variable $x0:= 16384; (: $X0 < $m :)
declare variable $cache := map {}; 
declare function mg:random($num as xs:integer) as xs:integer {
  let $key := xs:string($num)
  let $cached-value := map:get($cache, $key)
  return
   if ($cached-value) then
     $cached-value
   else
     let $random-value :=
       if ($num = 1) then 
        ($a * $x0 + $c) mod $m
       else 
        ($a * mg:random($num - 1) + $c) mod $m
     return 
      ( 
        $random-value,
        map:put($cache, $key, $random-value)
      )[1]
 };

for $i in (1 to 100) 
return mg:random($i)
```